# Rails 3 replacement for verify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails but was reading the docs about verifying params in my controllers and they seem to reference the verify method. But in rails 3 it shows that verify is deprecated. What is the new way of doing this?

The error i am getting is: verify was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin.

Is this still used but just in plugin form now or have they replaced it with another method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707071/rails-2-to-rails-3-method-verification-in-controllers-gone) will help you. So as you can see you don't need to write verifications inside your controllers anymore in Rails 3.

Comment: I saw that, but i am dealing specifically with PUT and POST where the params are in the body of the request, so the routes will match but i would like to validate the params.

Comment: @Jason: Shouldn't you make these validations inside your models? (by using validates_numericality_of, validates_presence_of etc.).

Comment: If that is the method that is recommended i can do that. I just stumbled across nested resources and that may take care of some of the issues i was experiencing with missing data.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality continues to be available in the [verification plugin](https://github.com/sikachu/verification).

Alternatively, all this plugin does is set up a [before filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), which is simple to do manually. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402345/rails-i18n-in-verification-rb-verify-method-does-not-work/5138555#5138555) for an example.