# equivalent for verify upgrading from rails 3 --> rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line in my rails 3 code:

```
  verify :method => :post, :only => [:destroy, :move], :redirect_to => {:action => :list}
```

When running my app I get this error:

```
undefined method `verify' for MyController:Class (NoMethodError)
```

How do I write it in rails 5?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072322/rails-3-replacement-for-verify

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
before_action :your_method_name, :only => [:destroy, :move]

def your_method_name
   #check here
   redirect_to :list_path
end
```